# django - Importing dictionary data into model data with Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I get the below model.py

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
     user_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user_name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    hobby = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    job = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
```

I created a user object instance named 'Elvin'.

I get the below views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import IntegrityError
from .models import User, Profile

item = { 'user': 'Elvin', 'hobby': 'horse riding', 'job': 'banker'}

def create(request):
    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(**item)
        profile.save()

    except IntegrityError:
        pass

    template = 'index.html'
    thing = Profile.objects.order_by('-hobby')
    context = {'thing':thing}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

However, it returns a ValueError. Cannot assign "'Elvin'": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.

I wonder how i can import my dictionary data into a ForeignKey data in model data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Profile` model contains a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model. So when we try to create the `Profile` object `user` field should be `User` instance. So change the value of `user` key in `item` to a user instance

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import IntegrityError
from .models import User, Profile, User


def create(request):
    # create the user instance first then 
    # make this object as value of key in the dictionary.

    user_ = User.objects.create(user_name='Elvin')
    item = { 'user': user_, 'hobby': 'horse riding', 'job': 'banker'}

    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(**item)    
    except IntegrityError:
        pass

    template = 'index.html'
    thing = Profile.objects.order_by('-hobby')
    context = {'thing':thing}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**NOTE**

When you try to create an object using `profile = Profile.objects.create(**item)` you don't need to call the `profile.save()` again, because `Profile.objects.create` is implicitly calling `save` method.